# Intellij IDEA doesn't highlight and resolve build.gradle file "guts" appropriately

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

Any task, method, variable and etc. usage is just colored into gray and displays a message `Cannot resolve symbol...`. How to enable proper build script analysis in Intellij IDEA for this?

Here is a screenshot of how it actually looks.

[image]

P.S.: all tasks and configuration blocks are running OK.

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50450